# How to index MultiIndex with Interval

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I would like to be able to filter the rows that contain the age group (1,2]. I am not sure how to do this.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xs`

```py
idx = pd.Interval(left=1, right=2)
df.xs(idx, level=1)
```

or `loc` with `axis` argument

```py
df.loc(axis=0)[:, idx]
```